# May I retake id by shmget() with different rights?

Tags: c, linux, ipc, shared-memory

## Prelude

I have one my own .so library (let's name it "lib.so"), and two applications, that use the library let's name it a.out & b.out. In the library I use the next (shown the idea, not the exact) code:

```
int a[N];

for (i = 0; i < N; i++) a[i] = i;
```

As I understand, since for every connected application there will be another set of variables, so at the moment when both application are running, there will be two copies of the `a` variable. There are some math formulas I use for `a` filling, they remain unchanged. So, since the `N` is quite big, I want to reduce the memory consumption and leave only one copy of the `a` in memory. So, I want to use shared memory mechanism. Since I write it under (and for) Linux, I want to use Unix System V.

## The problem

The first loaded application must initialise the array, all another connected applications will only read from that array, so I want to give them 0444 rights to that block:

```
id = shmget(..., ..., 0444 | IPC_CREATE | IPC_EXCL)
```

But the very first one must receive 0666 rights to fill the array:

```
id = shmget(..., ..., 0666 | IPC_CREATE | IPC_EXCL)
```

So I came up with the next code:

```
if ((id = shmget(..., ..., 0444 | IPC_CREATE | IPC_EXCL)) == -1)
{
   id = shmget(..., ..., 0666 | PC_CREATE);
   initdata(id) // shmat inside
}

char * data = (char *)shmat(id, 0, 0);
```

Now I have the problem. If I want to be ideologically right, I need to remove 0666 rights from the first copy I give it 0444 instead. So, the only way I see is to retake it with another call of `shmget` with 0444 params right after `initdata(id)` call;

```
   id = shmget(..., ..., 0666 | PC_CREATE);
   initdata(id) // shmat inside
   id = shmget(..., ..., 0444 | PC_CREATE);
```

But I have a few question about it:

1. Is it legal? May I retake it this way?
2. Does it make any sense at all?

---

Bonus question: is it ok to put a filename of temporary file from /tmp/ to `ftok()`?

Comment: Does your approach work?

Comment: OT: As `shmat()` returns  `void*` there is no need to cast (in C).

Comment: _Does your approach work?_

That was my question. May I do it this way or there is another one?

Comment: Why not try it and discuss with us what you observe? Setting up a minimal example of your use-case should not take too much time, shouln't it? However: **If** it works SO might be the wrong place to dicuss alternatives.